# django stream a dictionary multiple times w/o breaking JSON

Tags: python, json, django, stream

I want to stream a response using Django. In order to do so,
I have a view like this:

`def flights(request, query):
    req_obj = Flights.RequestObject(query)
    return StreamingHttpResponse(req_obj.make_response(), content_type="application/json")`

In order to produce the data for the stream, I have a generator function "make_response",
which is a method of the class "Flights", instantiated as "req_obj".

The generator function yields, at particular moments, a pure python dictionary.

```
def make_response(self):
   for _ in range(0,3):
      yield some_dict
      time.sleep(1)
```

This results in the following behaviour:

- after the first yield, the json content return is valid;
- after the second (and following) yields, the json content returned is NOT valid;

if the dictionary returned is something like this

> {"data": "some_data"}

,
after the second yield, the response the user receives is:

> {"data": "some_data"}{"data": "some_data"}

, which is NOT valid json.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
req_obj.update(req_obj.make_response())
```

which will update your initial dict with the values newly yielded from your method?

Comment: Hi, first of all, I would like to thank you for your help. Unfortunetly, I did not understand your answer.

Comment: i am guessing that this update would occur in the first argument of the streamingHttpResponse, unfortunetly, this does not work, because req_obj.make_response() is not an object, but rather a generator. @Omar

Comment: Ah yes correct @RafaelMarques, so how about inside the generator you do a :
yield self.update(some_dict)
I'm not sure how you're building the dict from the Flight object, but since you have access to it in the make_response you can perhaps use that to update the dictionary that is being yeilded

Comment: thats not the problem thoug.
The problem is that yielding a dictionary (equal or different) several time, produces something that is NOT a dictionary. @Omar

Comment: right so in your question it was returning two dictionaries, so the update would combine the values into one dictionary

Comment: My bad, I think I am misunderstanding the whole thing, the stream is resulting in the "double" dictionary, not sure if you can handle that django side

Comment: exactly. even though the update works as you say, the Stream and the Yield result in the returning of several dictionaries, which, combined, form an object which is not valid json, or even dict for that matter.

Comment: @RafaelMarques did you manage to solve this? If so what technique did you use? Did you try streaming a string object and parsing it as json on the other end?

Comment: No, I was unable to solve my situation with streaming. What I wanted, is to gradually return responses (return response A now, return response B a second from now, response C later, etc.). From what I could tell, streaming was not the appropriate way to do this, as streaming was used to send an already existing response, chuck by chunk, instead of returning multiple response objects whenever they become available. To be fair, I still don't know a good way to solve this hehe @omar

Answer (score 0):

The solution is on the client side (eg: browser). You need to interpret the JSON result when it comes. By definition of a stream you never know when it finished, so every time you receive some data on the client side, you need to interpret it as a self contain JSON message.

So in your case, the client would probably need to append the received JSON dictionary to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to manually "start" and "end" the json output. Example:

```py
def make_response(self):
   yield '['
   for _ in range(0,3):
      yield some_dict
      yield ','  #  you might add extra magic here to detect if this is the last time 
                 #  the loop will execute so you can skip the ','.
                 #  It will still be valid json regardless
      time.sleep(1)
   yield ']'
```