# Proper way of streaming JSON with Django

Tags: python, json, django

i have a webservice which gets user requests and produces (multiple) solution(s) to this request.
I want to return a solution as soon as possible, and send the remaining solutions when they are ready.

In order to do this, I thought about using Django's Http stream response. Unfortunately, I am not sure if this is the most adequate way of doing so, because of the problem I will describe below.

I have a Django view, which receives a query and answers with a stream response. This stream returns the data returned by a generator, which is always a python dictionary.
The problem is that upon the second return action of the stream, the Json content breaks.

If the python dictionary, which serves as a response, is something like {key: val}, after the second yield the returned response is  {key: val} {key: val}, which is not valid Json.

Any suggestions on how to return multiple Json objects at different moments in time?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: This question is a repost of a question I created yesterday, which has a bit more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469948/django-stream-a-dictionary-multiple-times-w-o-breaking-json/50470859?noredirect=1#comment87956272_50470859@Dalvtor

Comment: I can add more details, but the problem arises from yielding two dicts to a stream, so I don't believe that more details will modify the character of the problem. @Dalvtor

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding with something like 
for example

> > > import json
> > >
> > > json.dumps( {key: val} {key: val}, separators=('}', ':'))  #check it

Answer (score 0):

The solution is on the client side (eg: browser). You need to interpret the JSON result when it comes. By definition of a stream you never know when it finished, so everytime you receive some data on the client side, you need to interpret it as a self contain JSON message.