# Is it possible to stream JSON in Django with StreamingHTTPResponse or in any other way?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, httpresponse

I'm wondering if it's possible to correctly stream JSON in Django?

I've tried to use `StreamingHTTPResponse` but what I'm sending is incorrect JSON format - **expected [json], sending [json][json]..[json]**, each is separate array.

I kind of understand the idea - we cannot send [json ... json... json]
because it will be incomplete on all iterations but last (it's important to close the array bracket). But maybe I'm wrong. Please help me to understand how JSON can be streamed correctly.

According to documentation [StreamingHTTPResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse) mostly used for csv, but nowhere is it said that it cannot be used for JSON. If that's the case, how to make it work?

Would really appreciate any help, I'm trying to solve this mystery for a few days now.

```
def generator_chunk():
    ...
    yield df.to_json   # returns data like [json]

@api_view(['GET'])
def return_data(request):
    ...
    return StreamHttpResponse(generator_chunk)  # streams data like [json][json], which is not proper json format
```

Similar questions (which have no answer):

[Proper way of streaming JSON with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491360/proper-way-of-streaming-json-with-django)

[django stream a dictionary multiple times w/o breaking JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469948/django-stream-a-dictionary-multiple-times-w-o-breaking-json/50470859?noredirect=1#comment87956272_50470859@Dalvtor)

Comment: Are you streaming because the df.to_json is too large to hold in memory?

Comment: @MikeOrganek yes, I'm requesting data from db in chunks and then want to stream them if it's possible.

Comment: Is there a method you can call to see whether there is anything more to send?  In other words, after receiving the `df.to_json` but before you `yield` the value, can you see whether there are any more `df.to_json` records you need to stream?

Comment: yes, I can request the overall # of rows first.

Comment: If so, then prepend a `[` character to the first object, prepend a `,` to the following objects, and then append a `]` to the last one.  That will make it a valid JSON array of arrays or objects.

Comment: That's an interesting idea :) I might go with it if nothing else works. Although, I thought there should be some mechanism in place for such kind of stuff in Django. Appreciate you taking a minute to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code to send JSON stream with django:

```
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

    def download_logs(self, request):
        """
        :param request: Django HTTP Request

        :return: Django HTTP Response
        """
        def event_stream():
            while True:
                logs = self.retrieve_logs()
                if len(logs) > 0:
                    yield f"data: {json.dumps(logs)}\n\n"
                time.sleep(1)

        return StreamingHttpResponse(event_stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

On the client side, you will need to parse the JSON string representation.

Comment: Note that `f"data: {json.dumps(logs)}\n\n"` will load the entirety of `logs` into memory.